# showing that $|u|$ is invertible whenever $u$ is in a C* algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If I'm working in an inner product space then it is easy to show that

$$\left|\left|Av\right|\right|^2 = \langle Av,Av \rangle = \langle v,A^*Av\rangle =
\langle v, \sqrt{A^*A}\cdot \sqrt{A^*A}v \rangle =
\langle \sqrt{A^*A}v,  \sqrt{A^*A}v \rangle = 
\left|\left| \sqrt{A^*A}v\right|\right|^2$$

and therefore $ker(A) = ker(|A|)$ where $|A|=\sqrt{A^*A}$.  From here, we know an element is invertible iff its kernel is trivial.

However, I don't see why a C* algebra behaves anything like an inner-product space, a priori.

I'm new to C* algebras and I would appreciate hints.... but not a full solution.

Comment: Please write your questions so that they are understandable without their title: the title is the title, not the first sentence of the body. In your case, it is only the title that describes what you want to do.

Comment: oh sorry.  I guess I wasn't sure what to title it.  Are you suggesting the title is okay so long as it becomes redundant and I just restate it in the body?  I was honestly just doing this based on reading other questions....  I hadn't taken the time to review the rules.  Sorry if I violated some standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is a C$^*$-algebra and $u\in A$ is invertible, then $u^*u$ is invertible.  Now since $u^*u$ is normal, you can apply a functional calculus argument to show that $\sqrt{u^*u}$ is invertible.

Comment: The notes I'm studying don't mention the functional calculus once so I was kinda hesitant to use that result..... though we did learn this in the standard functional analysis course.  Is there any other way to think about it.... without the functional calculus?

Comment: No functional calculus?  May I ask how these notes define $|u|$?

Comment: $f(x) = \sqrt{x},x \ge 0$ and define $|a| = f(a^*a)$.

I'm not sure if the functional calculus is used in the definition of $\sqrt{x}$ but I suspect so; so I've included below what I think may be the functional calculus (but in these notes it's not called that... and it looks different than the version I remember)

Comment: Let $B$ be a unital C∗-algebra and let $a$ be a normal element of $B$. The map sending $f$ to $f(a)$ is an isometric ∗-isomorphism from $C(spec(a))$ to the C∗-subalgebra of $B$ generated by $a$ and the unit. Moreover, if $f(z) =  \sum_{k,l} a_{k,l}z^k\overline{z}^l$ is any polynomial in $z$ and $\overline{z}$, then
$f(a) =  \sum_{k,l} a_{k,l}a^k(a^*)^l$

Comment: Yep that's it.   Now Since $a^*a$ is invertible, $0\notin spec(a^*a)$.  So for $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, $spec(f(a^*a))=f(spec(a^*a))$, so $0\notin spec(f(a^*a))$, and therefore $f(a^*a)$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

The precise answer to your question depends on the way you define C$^*$-algebras and how you progress in building the theory. For instance, as soon as you know that all C$^*$-algebras admit a faithful representation into $B(H)$, you can repeat the argument you already know.

In any case, to work with $|u|$, you need some way to obtain square roots, which is usually functional calculus.

No matter how, as soon as you know that you can take square roots of positive elements, you can prove that if $a$ and invertible, then $a^{1/2}$ is invertible. Indeed, if $b$ is the inverse of $a$, you have $ab=ba=I$. We can rewrite the two equalities as 
$$
a^{1/2}(a^{1/2}b)=(ba^{1/2})a^{1/2}=I.
$$
So $a^{1/2}$ has a left and a right inverse, which will necessarily be equal and thus $a^{1/2}$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks!  This is actually what I wanted to do at first since I was aware of this from other readings.... however, I wanted to remain ..... faithful ^_^ to my current text.